# .bat file to create local user and set password to never expire

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, windows-11

I'm trying to create a .bat file that can add a local (non-admin) account and sets the password to never expire. However, when I run it, I don't see the account show up in Computer Management > Local Users and Groups > Users.

My bat file contains the following:

```bash
@echo off
net user IT password /add
echo “Adding IT user”
WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE Name='IT' SET PasswordExpires=FALSE
echo “Setting password to never expire”
```

I have also tried this (with and without the double quotation marks):

```bash
@echo off
start cmd /c "net user IT password /add"
echo “Adding IT user”
start cmd /k "WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE Name='IT' SET PasswordExpires=FALSE"
echo “Setting password to never expire”
```

Comment: The first thing I'd ask you to do is to replace those curly/smart quotes with straight/dumb quotes.

Comment: I'd suggest that Users would need to have elevated privileges in order to process this. For that, especially as `WMIC.exe` is deprecated, and reportedly to be removed from newer, _(Win11+)_, Operating Systems, I'd advise doing everything using `powershell.exe` instead. You could, if you wish, still do that from a batch file. Example: ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "New-LocalUser \"IT"\ -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString \"P@ssw0rd\" -AsPlainText -Force) -FullName \"IT User\" -Description \"Account for IT Department user\" –PasswordNeverExpires"```.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have Administrator Privileges.
Try to run it as Admin.